# I am trying to start Foreground service on older API version. Work on APIs 26+

Tags: java, android, notifications, foreground, foreground-service

I need to start my app service foreground. My code work fine with API level 26 and newer, but not with older APIs level. On older version Service is shown in running service but don't send the starting notification. What I need to change to my code, why isn't working?

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        messageIntent.setAction(getString(R.string.receiver_receive));



        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT)
                .setOngoing(false).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            startForeground(1, builder.build());
        }

    }
```

Starting the Service

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, SocketService.class));
        else
            this.startService(new Intent(this, SocketService.class));
    }
```

Comment: How do you start this `Service`?

Comment: @JeelVankhede
`protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  // Bind to LocalService
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
  bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, SocketService.class));
        else
            this.startService(new Intent(this, SocketService.class));
 }`

Comment: `startForeground(1, builder.build());` put this line outside of if condition in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Method `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(...)` already contain `if` block:

```
public static void startForegroundService(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        // Pre-O behavior.
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Just call `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, pushIntent)`.

And you need to move `startForeground` outside `if` block:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    ...        
}
startForeground(1, builder.build());
```

Also, don't forget to call `notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)` on older APIs (if notification doesn't show automatically). `NOTIFICATION_ID` must be NOT ZERO!!!

Answer (score 1):

start service for below apis in else statement.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    // only for newer versions
      Intent pushIntent = new Intent(this, ClassName.class);
      startForegroundService(pushIntent);
} else {
      Intent pushIntent = new Intent(this, ClassName.class);
      startService(pushIntent);
}
```

Comment: This is OK, I have similar to my code, but the i don't get the starting notification, and my app don't work when I close from tasks. I think that is something with notification code, I update the question.
PS: Service is shown in running services

Comment: did you try to put out the notification code from if block?

Answer (score 0):

Write code for devices with api lower than 26 same as written in if statement excluding the part of notification channel because notification channel is not supported in devices with version lower than 26

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // you had written code for device version greater than O
    } else {
       //You need to write code for device with lower version here
    }
```

Comment: I put that code in else statement, now I have the start notification but not work properly, I don't receive other notification or messages.

`else {
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "5");
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   builder.setContentTitle(title);
   builder.setContentText(text);

   startForeground(4, builder.build());
  }`